# Terraform roll-out strategy

Tags: terraform

I need some help regarding terraform module roll-out.

we have rolled out a terraform module change which includes addition/deletion of new/old variables.
There are around 150+ .tf files which call this module.It's a real pain having to go and change all the variables on the caller.

Any better strategies without having to change the variables on all 150+ .tf files?

Thanks.

Comment: What about simple find and replace for all files at once?

Comment: If your team owns all the ROOT modules then what Marcin said. You can use a tool like Hound to search your codebase for that. 

If you have teams using the aforementioned module, then bump the module version and make the update elective for the consumers. That way you distribute the responsibility to deprecate those variables.

Comment: Thanks Guys for quick response.I will try the above and keep you posted